# 32 bit Python project to 64 bit Python project

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, 32bit-64bit

I have one project build on 32 bit Python 2.7 (most probably in windows environment). Now I pulled the project in my Ubuntu 16.06 (64 bit) Python 2.7 virtual environment. But I am facing the following error when I run it.

> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Note: If the project run on Ubuntu 16.04 (32 bit) the error disappears.

What could be the problem and how can I run the project on Ubuntu 16.06 (64 bit)?